# Optimizing Pubsub Pattern with Angular and RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am implementing a publish and subscribe pattern using an Angular service and an RxJS Subject. The service if firehosed with updates from the backend and has to filter these updates so that any given compenent only gets the updates they sign up for. It may be easier if I give my working example.

Here is the service code:

```
public getUpdates(updatesIWant: UPDATE[]): Observable<UPDATE[]> {
  return this.updateSubject.pipe(
    map(updates => updates.filter(update => updatesIWant.indexOf(update) != -1)));
}
```

And here is the component code:

```
this.updateService.getUpdates(this.updatesIWant).subscribe(updates => {
  this.processUpdates(updates);
}
```

This works, but when receiving thousands of updates a second, it becomes inefficient. How can I optimize this pattern? Is there any way I can incorporate a custom rxjs operator that will do the job, or perhaps a webworker?

Comment: Well, it heavily depends on what you want to get. What technology you're using for delivering those thousands of events to the application in the browser? What are those thousands of events? Why do you filter out data in the event streams instead of filtering out events themselves (I mean rxjs `filter()` operator)? Why do you work with them as with the arrays instead of emitting items one by one and filter them out instead of arrays? I'd say it'd be more convenient to emit them one by one. And so on and so forth. Again - it heavily depends on what you want to achieve, which is not clear here.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov thanks for the response. I am getting batches of updates from the backend, which is why I need to work with arrays. The updates themselves are objects. I have not looked into rxjs filter yet, but I will.

Comment: The fact that you're getting batches of updates from backend does not necessarily mean that you **have** to work with them like that. Consider following construct: `flatMap(batch => from(batch))`. It will emit items from each batch one by one instead of emitting them as an array. Consequently, you can write `filter()` operator after that with a simple filtering expression based on one item instead of going through an array. Most likely it can be optimized but still it is hard to suggest something meaningful looking at such a small piece of code not conveying the whole idea.

Comment: Also, if you need ultimate performance then rxjs may not suit you. You need to perform really deep performance testing in order to understand if rxjs puts too big overhead. The question is - aren't you trying to solve the problem that does not exist? How do you know that the code is not performant enough?

Comment: You may also want to consider another server side service that does this filtering *before* it swamps your UI with changes. That way you only need to send to the browser the pieces it actually cares about. That could go along way to resolve any performance issues.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov I used firefox's performance tab measuring 20,000 updates per second and a hotspot was found at the service's function that I have written above. I was unaware that rxjs was known for having a large overhead. Would you mind recommending an alternative that is performance based?

Comment: @DeborahK I would totally agree. Unfortunately I am only able to experiment with front end solutions for now.

Comment: @michaelblxck, I did not say that rxjs overhead is big, and for most of the "usual" applications it can be dropped from consideration completely. What I'm saying is that for your particular application with high volume data stream it _may_ be big enough to be seriously considered, but first you need to make sure that it is indeed the problem you're seeing. If you're saying that firefox puts finger on your function - well, then I'd start with refactoring it.

Comment: @michaelblxck, First, I'd drop all the filtering and other maps and transformations. Just subscribe to the raw data source with an empty function and see if rxjs is able to handle at least that. Then, I'd add `flatMap()` transformation and checked if it still holds. Then, I'd add `filter()` on the converted stream and checked again. Doing these baby steps you'd get the idea of what it is able to handle, where it fails, and what you should not do.